# Questions about Octave 3.8.2 compilation on CentOS 6.4

Tags: compilation, fortran, octave, blas, fortran77

I try to compile Octave 3.8.2 on CentOS 6.4 （serve）, but there's an error:

> A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings.

I'm so confused. I compiled a BLAS and a LAPACK myself, and I added their path to bashrc. But this error appeared again. I try to change fflags to ff2c as other resources suggested, but this error also occurred.

I found the following [guide](http://lab.uchicago.edu/2013/05/16/building-octave-3-6-4-from-source/) and [discussion of my error](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2012-09/msg00518.html).

Comment: Could you please upload your config.log? Btw, there is Octave 4.0.0rc3. Here are instructions for centos: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_GNU/Linux#Red_Hat_Enterprise.2FCentOS

Comment: I didn't add the image into the post as it would perhaps be much better instead if you could write in the content as text.  I also guessed at a sensible description for your links, so an update to those would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am going through this, and I had the same issues that you are mentioning.  I solved it by using the auto config options to point it to the correct library, e.g.

`./configure --with-lapack=/path/to/liblapack.so.3 --with-blas=/path/to/libf77blas.so.3`

It compiles and produces an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `OpenBLAS` instead of the common `BLAS` and `LAPACK` packages. It is written in the Octave documentation:

> "Accelerated BLAS libraries such as OpenBLAS (https://www.openblas.net/) or ATLAS (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net) are recommended for best performance.  The reference implementation (http://www.netlib.org/blas) is slow, unmaintained, and suffers from certain bugs in corner case inputs."

You can download it from https://www.openblas.net/ and install it with the classical `./configure && make %% sudo make install`. After this move the libraries generated by `OpenBLAS` to `/usr/lib64` and run:

`./configure -with-blas="-lopenblas"`

Add other flags and arguments to configure if needed.